# Visual Studio alternative of command "code ."

Tags: visual-studio, cmd, visual-studio-2019

We've all seen this command sequence:

```
git clone [someRepo]
cd [someRepo]
code .
```

This will clone some repo, get into the folder and open it using Visual Studio Code. Without going into arguments whether VSCode or VS is better - I do use Visual Studio. Is there some VS command that is similar to "code .", that will open some solution directly from git bash/powershell/cmd?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried : start devenv.exe filename.extension . This will your file directly in VS

Comment: @Bouam Thanks, it works (as long as you add devenv location in PATH vars). In any case, it remains a bit uncomfortable and I will keep using UI navigation for now. You can post this as an answer so I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an improvement of my first answer  you can use :

```
git clone [someRepo]
cd [someRepo]
start devenv .
```

It will open visual studio with the current directory.